# jQuery class selectors and $(this)

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, this

I have a plugin that I'm trying to call, and use an attribute from a parameter defined in the DOM.  For example

```
<a href="somewhere.html" class="my_a">blah</a>
```

And I have a "box" plugin, so I want to do

```
$(".my_a").box({

attribute1: "something",
attribute2: $(this).attr('href')
});
```

So that one of the parameters passed to the box function is the value of the href from the a of the class that was clicked, however using $(this) doesn't seem to be work.

Any thoughts?

Comment: did u check the plugin manual?

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using a class name selector I'd suggest caching the element lookup

```
var el = $(".my_a");
el.box({
   attribute1: "something",
   attribute2: el.attr('href')
});
```

Comment: why would you want to do this?  Just use `this` inside the box function (not in the way he's trying to above) to do whatever it is you want to do.  There's no point passing in the href of the link when you already have it in the jQuery object.  See my answer below

Comment: I'm assuming the "box" jQuery plug-in is a from a 3rd party that you can't or don't want to change the internals of.

Comment: a, fair enough, i was assuming he's writing the box plugin

Answer (score 1):

`this` isn't in the correct context at that point for the targeted element.

You'd need to separately gather the information and pass it in to the box plugin, or modify the plugin itself.

```
$('.my_a').click(function( e ){

    var el = $(e.currentTarget);

    e.preventDefault();

    el.box({

        attribute1: 'something',
        attribute2: el.attr('href')

    });

});
```

I assume the box plugin handles the click event, so this isn't the greatest example, but it's the only way to get the attribute of the element that was actually clicked.

Comment: If the links are grouped under a common parent element it'd be better to use the .delegate() then a class selector that would bind to each element individually http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Answer (score 0):

Using `this` will not work, I think in this case because the `this` property refers to the object you are passing to `box()` (e.g. `{attribute1: .., attribute2: ...}`)...so you should do this: `$(".my_a").attr('href')`

**EDIT:**

```
$(".my_a").each(function(i, el){
    $(el).box({
        attribute1: "something",
        attribute2: $(el).attr("href")
    });
});
```

Comment: That doesn't work because if I have several links of the same class, it will only grab the href of the first link

Comment: you're probably better off not passing in an attribute of the thing you're actually trying to modify (you'd have to change it if your link changes).  Inside that box function he'll have access to `this` and can do whatever he wants there

Comment: what is "el" set to? If it is set to the element you need than you don't need to look it up again with $()

Answer (score 0):

the $(this).attr('href') assumes that youre on a event scope for the .my_a object, but you're not on this scope!

for this reaon you have to call it by $('.my_a').attr('href')

Answer (score 0):

You can call `box` method for each element with specified class.

```
$(".my_a").each(function() {
    $(this).box({
        attribute1: "something",
        attribute2: $(this).attr('href')
    });
});
```

This code traverses over all elements with class `my_a` and sets theirs `box`.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to pass in the attribute of the link to your function.

Once you're inside your box function you can set whatever attributes you want.  For example:

```
$.fn.box = function(attributes){
  // this now refers to a jQuery object that contains your link.  So use it here
  var href = this.attr('href');
  // so something with attributes and href
}
```

I don't know what you're doing inside your box function however so it's hard to comment further, but there's no reason you'd want to pass in an attribute of the same link that you're fetching with jquery.

Comment: I agree, but I wasn't clear on whether or not he is writing the plugin.